# Which structure should I use for firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am building a application where purchase bills are generated. Now I am storing the bills as `bills-(collection)--
bill1(doc)` the problem is bills are generated more often so if I store like trillions of docs can I query it efficiently? Is this model efficient and is it scalable? Or should I use `user(collection)-user1(doc)--userBills(subcollection)-billone(doc)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore doesn't really care how many documents you store in a collection.  It scales massively, and queries for N documents will always be equally efficient, no matter the size of the collection.  Do whatever is most convenient for your queries.

Comment: Thanks! I am doing it as the first type storin all bill in one collection.